# How to write xpath for a button with class attribute?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have just started working on Selenium-Ruby . 
My html looks something like this-

```
<button class="check column btn btn-invisible">
   <i class="icon-column-p"></i>
    "Check Column"
</button>
```

I want to click on the button, what would be the best xpath to access it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test against the text of the button with:

```xml
//button[contains(., '"Check Column"')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

//button[@class='check column btn btn-invisible']

Or

//button[contains(@class, 'btn')]